# NiFi PutSolrContentStream How do I add path params?

Tags: curl, solr, apache-nifi

I am running a 3 node SOLR cloud and have connectivity to zookeeper via NiFi. I am wondering how to add path parameters you would see from a regular solr update to the PutSOLRContentStream processor.

my working curl:

```
/solr/my_collection/update&stream.file=/opt/files/$file&commit=true&separator=%7C&stream.contentType=text/csv;charset=utf-8&fieldnames=...
```

Errors I'm getting from PutSOLRContentStream processor: (taken from nifi-app.log)

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error 
from server at 
http://my_solr_server:8983/solr/my_collection_shard#: Expected mime type 
application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>


<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing 
/solr/my_collection_shard#/update/extract&amp;commit=true&amp;separator=%7C&amp;
charset=utf-8&amp;fieldnames=... Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
```

How do I convert my curl into a working PutSOLRContentStreamProcessor? (Specifically, how can i properly fill out the "Content Stream Path" and "Content-Type" fields in the processor, and whether or not I need to add any further fields)

Answer (score 0):

The Content Stream Path should be only the path of the update handler, like "/update/extract".

For any other parameters you want to send on the request, add a user defined property by clicking the + icon in the top-right corner of the properties window.

Here is an example:

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42210/using-solrs-extracting-request-handler-with-apache.html

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with configuring PutSolrContentStreamProcessor. I have a standard solr server running locally and a solr collection named : party and I'm indexing json docs of companies/parties in that core.

Following is the configuration that worked for me.

[image]

Note that the Solr location contains the **full path to the Solr collection** : http://localhost:8983/solr/party and having the Collection value set to 'party' or keeping the value empty didn't have any effect. Basically you need to have the full Solr path defined correctly in "**SolrLocation**" for this to work.

Solr version : 7.6

Nifi version : 1.10.0-SNAPSHOT